# Apache ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Ubuntu with php enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

**Context:** I'm trying to copy my Wordpress - WP site locally on Ubuntu. My ultimate goal is to migrate it to Django-CMS.

I'm using Vagrant with a Virtualbox - VB. A Lamp stack is installed in the VB with Apache/2.4.29, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and PHP 7.2.

When I load following PHP ('bonjour.php') page:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Bonjour le monde depuis ' . dirname( __FILE__ ) . '</p>'; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

everything is fine. I get the page rendered as:

```
Bonjour le monde depuis /var/www/math-wp
```

However when I try to load `index.php` page from Wordpress:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I get the error message `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when reaching `localhost` page.

What can be the root cause of the error? How can I investigate? Is there log files that can be usefull?

Some additional elements:

- MySQL is installed and running well.
- I can properly access the WP DB listed in wp-config.php with the user
  and password listed in the same file.
- I changed in WP DB site_url and home_url (with wp CLI) to
  `http://localhost`.

Thanks!

If that can be usefull, the Apache2 configuration file I use is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        #
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        # ServerName math-wp.com
        # ServerAlias www.math-wp.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/math-wp"
        DirectoryIndex bonjour.php
        <Directory "/var/www/math-wp">
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.math-wp.com.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.math-wp.com.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you restart apache after the switch? sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Yes I did restarted Apache. Thanks for taking care!

Comment: Do you have your "Listen" directives in your vhost files or in /etc/apache2/ports.conf? You should have a line similar to : Listen 80

Comment: Also, try running this command and check if your problem is solved: sudo a2endmod ssl && sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: @PatrickSimard Thanks Patrick for taking. I indeed have a `Listen 80` directive in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and I enabled the modules you mentioned in your comments. However, this doesn't solve the issue. However, I updated the question with some elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error.

There was a mistake in `wp_config.php` file. Strangely adding the wp instruction

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

solved the issue.